# Permanent redirect (301) based on query string

Tags: http, redirect

Consider a website that has to support legacy URLs through the following format:

```
http://example.com/?some_param=value --> http://example.com/value
```

Though the root page is fully functional, and never redirects otherwise.

So basically, redirecting to an internal page according to a query param. If the parameter is missing, the request is considered to be a standard once, and not redirect.

Is it acceptable to permanently redirect (HTTP 301) based on query strings only? Do crawl bots properly distinguish between the two scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the request returns a HTTP 301 response, the "crawl bot" should recursively crawl, until either, it recognizes a possible infinite loop or receives a non-redirecting response.

Search engines in particular usually only store the response of the content returning HTTP 20x  when requesting an HTTP 301.

With that said, crawling behavior will obviously differ, depending on implementation.